# C++ : use of class and constructor

Tags: c++, class, quantlib

I am having a rough using the QuantLib::TimeSeries class from the QuantLib library. My problem doesn't relate to QuantLib and its intricacies, but in more general C++ class use I think.

The QuantLib::TimeSeries is described [here](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_time_series.html). In my code (that returns absolutely nothing for now), I provide a series of dates in a std::vector and a series of prices contained in std::vector. The QuantLib::TimeSeries object is supposed to tie together the dates and the prices.

```
#include<ql\quantlib.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<QuantLib::Date> dates;
    std::vector<std::double> quotes;

        dates.push_back(Date(12,Nov, 2012));
    dates.push_back(Date(13,Nov, 2012));
    dates.push_back(Date(14,Nov, 2012));

    quotes.push_back(40.05);
    quotes.push_back(40.84);
    quotes.push_back(41.03);


    // Below is the line I am stuck at 
    QuantLib::TimeSeries<std::vector<QuantLib::Date>, std::vector<double>> series(dates.begin(), dates.end(), quotes.begin());

    // Now do something with all the stuff above
    // ... ...

    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate someone provided guidance, helping me to make this work.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Also, what is `closes`?

Comment: Could your problem be that `closes.begin()` should be `quotes.begin()` instead?

Comment: Your include is wrong, you’re not allowed to use `\\` in the path.

Comment: Konrad, Visual Studio automatically complete with a backslash after I type 'ql'. This has never been a problem so far, eg http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/matrix-decomposition-with-quantlib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your difficult line should be just something like:

```
QuantLib::TimeSeries<double> series(dates.begin(), dates.end(), quotes.begin());
```

From the documentation you linked:

```
template<class T, class Container = std::map<Date, T>>
class QuantLib::TimeSeries< T, Container >;
```

The first parameter is the type you store, in your case `double` and the second is probably one the container used to use as implementation, and it already has a default implementation, so nothing is needed.

Comment: Oh! It seems this was the problem. Thank you for the hint. That now compiles.